# Numerical Spherical derivatives

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, spherical-coordinates

I am hoping someone may be able to dispel a doubt I have.
I am working on an application where I have a digital representation of a terrain. I generate a spherical representation of the terrain around a location on this terrain (i.e. I end up radial distance, azimuthal angle, and polar angle). Putting aside the fact that I am going to have many 'discontinuities' (due to the presence of horizons), I would like to find the first and second derivatives... in order to characterize the curvature. What formulae would I use? Would it suffice to numerically differentiate as you would in the cartesian planes? or would I need to adjust this differentiation based  the formulae found for gradient differentiation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

I hope this makes sense.

Here is an image where the color represents depth and the x and y axis represent angular values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWE6t.png)

M

Comment: Your description is too vague. Without equations or a specific example of the data at your disposal is not realistic that you will get any help. Rightly or wrongly, the image that comes to my mind is that you need to compute the Gauss curvature of a smooth surface. You specifically mention first and second derivatives, but you do not identify the function. You should edit your question and add more information.

Comment: @CarlChristian. There is no equations or functions because I am dealing with the spherical representation of a real terrain. I am looking at differentiating **numerically** r (here representing depth) in relation to the azimuth and polar angles

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

Discrete data $f(x_1^i,\dots,x_n^i)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ can reasonably be differentitated only in the following way:
$$
\partial_jf(x_1^i,\dots\dots,x_n^i)\approx \frac{f(x_1^i,\dots,x_{j-1}^i, x_j^{i+1},x_{j+1}^i,\dots,x_n^i)-
f(x_1^i,\dots\dots,x_n^i)}{x_j^{i+1}-x_j^i}\,.
$$
This is a difference quotient known in numerical mathematics.
If you like you can make this symmetric by using $x_j^{i+1}$ and $x_j^{i-1}\,.$
The write up of a mixed second partial derivative should be straightforward.

Comment: So essentially differentiate numerically as if you were in Cartesian space

Comment: @marcos I did not say that. The $x_j^i$ are the coordinates that label your data. From the vague description of OP I gather that you have $n=3$ and spherical coordinates. Presumably $x_1=r,x_2=\theta,x_3=\varphi\,.$ The quotient I wrote is an ordinary partial derivative w.r.t. those coordinates. My point is that you can only start with that since discrete points is all you have. You can later try to smoothe the data and see if that improves anything. Please add more maths to your post to make this a more fruitful discussion. There is no gadget that turns garbage into gold.